# Any possible reasons why clients are not receiving messages [Signal Server 3.21/Signal Client 4.57.1]

Tags: java, android, server

community,

Can't solve the problem for about 10 days

My setup (used this [guide](https://github.com/madeindra/signal-setup-guide))

Server version 3.21 works behind nginx reverse proxy with Let's encrypt cert. No errors in nginx error log file.
Android clients version 4.53.6 and 4.57.1

On the server side all external dependencies (GCM, GCP, APN, Amazon S3, etc) **aren't** configured. Commented in code when caused an errors.
Client has whisper.store with domain cert file. I've checked unindentified delivery and zkgroup keys.
Packets are transmitted between the client and the server. There is no errors in enginx logs.

**I can register, see other clients, send message, but not receive.**

**What are the possible reasons why clients do not receive messages?**

Comment: Though your link text is correct, it takes us to https://madeindra/signal-setup-guide Please update that!

Comment: @MehantKammakomati It's correct, there is an installation guide on that link. I've used a few guides from this repo (mainly https://github.com/madeindra/signal-setup-guide/tree/master/signal-server-3.21)